# How to Update an array with Dapper Extension?

Tags: c#, .net, invalidoperationexception, dapper-extensions

I get from DB my entities' list, change some properties and try to Update in in DB.

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
cn.Open();
var dataPredicate = Predicates.Field<Data>(f => f.Id, Operator.Eq, new [] {1, 2, 3}); // of course it's for an example 
var data = cn.GetList<Data>(dataPredicate);

foreach (var element in data)
{
     element.Status = StatusEnum.Pending;
     element.LastChange = DateTime.Now;
}

foreach (var activeRequest in data)
{
     cn.Update(activeRequest);
}
cn.Close();
}
```

I tried also:

```
var updated = data.Select(s => new Data
{
     Id = s.Id,
     CreateDate = s.CreateDate,
     ForeignId = s.ForeignId,
     LastChange = DateTime.Now,
     Status = RequestStatus.Pending
 });
```

And I get **InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.**

I don't have any problem with another operations.

How can I Update it correctly?

Comment: `var data = cn.GetList<Data>(dataPredicate).ToList();` try this

Comment: Unrelated but no need to `cn.Close();` inside a using statement.

Comment: @v.shashenko I thought the same way, but they say the opposite: [Dapper-Extensions on github](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions)

Comment: @Anri , it's helpful, thank you. I thought first foreach did the same.

Comment: @lyha Added answer with detailed explanations, you can accept it if it's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cn.GetList<Data>(dataPredicate)` returns `IEnumerable` and every time you use it with `foreach` actual sql query gets executed and `DataReader` is used to provide `IEnumerable` with data.

So in your case you are executing `DataReader` twice, and second time you are trying to do `Update` query on the same connection with `DataReader` still open.

If this is desirable behaviour (too much data and you do want to load it one by one with `DataReader`) you should use separate connection for `Update` queries.

Another option will be to load all the data to list and then iterate trough it, like this:

```
var data = cn.GetList<Data>(dataPredicate).ToList();
```